# Large arrays with default values in Minizinc data file?

Tags: modeling, minizinc

How to model a large array e.g. "array[1..10000000] of int: A;" which has a lot of 0 as default value. Is there a way to specify "default" value to MiniZinc in order to reduce the data file size?

Answer (score 0):

MiniZinc is a declarative language where you can not change the value of an assigned variable. This makes the question a bit strange, there is no need of a default value since the value of a variable can't be changed.

I would use an array comprehension `[if i == 3 then i else 0 endif  | i in 1..10000000]` and switch the condition and result of the if-statement depending on what you need.

There might a another way of representing the array? An array that is mostly empty does not sound very effective.